# How to pre select the first row in LWC datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, js

Currently, I am using the above code to preselect the first row:

```
//preselect the first invoice row
setTimeout(() => this.selectedRows = this.invoiceList.map(record=>record.id));
```

The `invoiceList` is a list of invoices displayed in my datatable (invoiceList = datatable's data)

By using this code, all the rows of my datatable were going to be preselected, however maxrowselection is 1. So only the first row is preselected. In the browser's console I get this error:

```
The number of keys in selectedRows for lightning:datatable exceeds the limit defined by maxRowSelection.
```

I don't know how to access only the first element of my list. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method

> creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

That's why you're getting that warning in the browser's console.
In order to get only the first element, you can just access it via its index (0):

```
//preselect the first invoice row
setTimeout(() => this.selectedRows = [this.invoiceList[0].id]);
```

If you have an instance variable that holds the max row selection value, you can write a function to populate the `selectedRows` array with at most that number of ids.

```
fillSelectedRows() {
    const endIndex = Math.min(this.maxRowSelection, this.invoiceList.length);
    const preselectedIds = [];
    for (let i=0; i<endIndex; i++) {
        preselectedIds.push(this.invoiceList[i].id);
    }
    this.selectedRows = preselectedIds;
}
```

Since [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) allows a second parameter greater than the array's length, the same method can be written as

```
fillSelectedRows() {
    this.selectedRows = this.invoiceList.slice(0, this.maxRowSelection).map(row => row.id);
}
```

Comment: For the latter code block, just `fillSelectedRows() { this.selectedRows = this.invoiceList.slice(0, this.maxRowSelection).map(row => row.id); }` will suffice. Unlike many other languages, JavaScript is smart enough to stop at the end of an array automatically. This also creates a copy, so no need to do so "manually."

Comment: @sfdcfox You're right, I'm going to update the answer, thanks for the tip. Anyway I'd say "`slice()` is smart enough..."